# Print a string from a pointer to its member class

Tags: c++, string

So I'm trying to print a string, but I get no output. However the other values in the class prints just fine.

In main I have a for loop that prints the the values for the Skill class. In Skill I have a pointer to the Ability class.

```
class Skill {
private:
    Ability* ability;
public:
    Ability* GetAbility() {
        return ability;
    };
}
```

It gets assigned in the constructor like this:

```
Skill::Skill(Ability* ability){
    this->ability = ability;
 }
```

The Ability class contains just a Name and a score.

```
class Ability {
private:
    string name;
    float score;
    public:
    Ability(string name, float score) {
        this->name = name;
        this->score = score;
    };
    string Name() { return name; }
    float GetScore() { return score; }
};
```

Now in main I create a few skills and assign an ability to it. as is a container class that initializes a few ablities in a vector and I can get an ability based on its name.

```
Skill s* = new Skill[2]
s[0] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Strength"));
s[1] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Charisma"));
```

And then we print

```
cout << s[i].GetAbility()->Name() << " " << s[i].GetAbility()->GetScore();
```

However the only output I get is the score. No name what so ever and I can't figure it out. I've tried a few things, but still noting is printing. I'm sure I'm missing something simple that will make me facepalm, but in my defense I haven't written C++ in over 10 years. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: as.GetAbility looks like this:

```
Ability AbilityScores::GetAbility(string abilityName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < abilityScores.size(); i++) {
        if (abilityScores[i].Name() == abilityName) {
            return abilityScores[i];
        }
    }
    return Ability();
}
```

abilityScores is a vector

Comment: `Skill s* = new Skill[2]` just allocates these instances using the automatically generated default constructor (taking the missing `;` for a typo here). Your `name` member is set to `""`. Either use a setter function for `name`, or allocate these instances separately using your constructor definition.

Comment: How can this code possibly compile? `Skill::Skill` takes an `Ability*`, but you pass it `&as.GetAbility()...` which is the address of the pointer to the actual `Ability`. Have you turned up the warning level of your compiler to hear it scream at you?

Comment: You use `s[0] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Strength"));`, but in your `Skill` class you define `Ability* GetAbility()` as accepting no argument.

Comment: Please show us what is behind `as.GetAbility`, also make sure you're not returning addresses of local variables that are outlived by their pointer.

Comment: It's an empty c++ project in visual studio 2019. I haven't changed any warning levels. Changing the & tosses me errors.

Comment: Updated it to show as.GetAbility. as is declared in main as AbilityScores as;

Comment: If you turn the warning levels up to 4, your compiler should tell you you're taking the address of a temporary variable. The value returned by `as.GetAbility` only live until the assignment is performed. Why not have `AbiltyScores::GetAbility` return `&abiilityScores[i]` instead? Now you're returning the address of something that lives in your main function (ie has a long lifetime)

Comment: That works like charm. Thank you @Botje and everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AbilityScores::GetAbility()` method is returning an `Ability` object *by value*, which means it returns a *copy* of the source `Ability`, and so your `Skill` objects will end up holding *dangling pointers* to temporary `Ability` objects that have been destroyed immediately after the `Skill` constructor exits.  So your code has *undefined behavior*.

`AbilityScores::GetAbility()` needs to return the `Ability` object *by reference* instead:

```cpp
Ability& AbilityScores::GetAbility(string abilityName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < abilityScores.size(); i++) {
        if (abilityScores[i].Name() == abilityName) {
            return abilityScores[i];
        }
    }
    throw ...; // there is nothing to return!
}

...

Skill s* = new Skill[2];
s[0] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Strength"));
s[1] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Charisma"));

...
```

If you want to return a default `Ability` when the `abilityName` is not found, consider using `std::map` instead of `std::vector`:

```cpp
private:
    std::map<std::string, Ability> abilityScores;

AbilityScores::AbilityScores() {
    abilityScores["Strength"] = Ability("Strength", ...);
    abilityScores["Charisma"] = Ability("Charisma", ...);
    ...
}

Ability& AbilityScores::GetAbility(string abilityName) {
    // if you don't mind Name() returning "" for unknown abilities...
    return abilityScores[abilityName];

    // otherwise...
    auto iter = abilityScores.find(abilityName);
    if (iter == abilityScores.end()) {
        iter = abilityScores.emplace(abilityName, 0.0f).first;
    }
    return iter->second;
}

...

Skill s* = new Skill[2];
s[0] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Strength"));
s[1] = Skill(&as.GetAbility("Charisma"));

...
```

Otherwise, return the `Ability` object *by pointer* instead:

```cpp
Ability* AbilityScores::GetAbility(string abilityName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < abilityScores.size(); i++) {
        if (abilityScores[i].Name() == abilityName) {
            return &abilityScores[i];
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
    // or:
    abilityScores.emplace_back(abilityName, 0.0f);
    return &(abilityScores.back());
}

...

Skill s* = new Skill[2];
s[0] = Skill(as.GetAbility("Strength"));
s[1] = Skill(as.GetAbility("Charisma"));

...
```